# Google analytics unauthorized access (401)

Tags: windows-services, google-analytics, http-status-code-401

One month ago I developed a windows service which calls some Google anaytics APIs and the code is scheduled to execute each 15 minutes. It has worked properly till 5 days ago when I checked the event viewer I saw that the service raised unauthorized access (401) exception in each connection to Google API. When I restarted the service it again started working properly.

What could be the reason?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you're obtaining an authentication token on startup and using that for all subsequent requests. Authentication tokens do expire eventually; when you get a 401, you should re-authenticate and get a new token.

Comment: Probably you are right since I used singleton pattern to create AnlyticsService object and it is a lifetime object. I used .NET Google analytics library to connect to APIs.

Comment: public static AnalyticsService GetAnalyticsService() { if (_service == null) { _service = new AnalyticsService(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationName"]); _service.setUserCredentials(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Username"], System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"]); } return _service; } Does this initialization set authentication token?

Comment: I don't know - and code doesn't format very well. It's more a matter of _when_ you run that code - you need to rerun it any time you get a 401, to get a new token.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you are using one of the authentication mechanisms such as AuthSub which require you to "sign" requests.  Embedded in this signature is a timestamp.  If you computer does not have the correct time it will fail.

With this said, could it be a Daylight Savings issue?  Does the computer you are running it on have the "Windows Patch" to address the changes when daylight savings takes place ([more info](http://it.rockefeller.edu/index.php?page=info.dst)).

I had a problem like this too just this past weekend.  I think modifying the "Automatically adjust clock for Daylight Saving Time" setting fixed it.

Maybe when you restarted the Service "corrected" itself for the time.

Comment: Cool! I have to wait for some week to find out whether it happens again or not! But the date when my service start raising exception was 3 days before October 31st